# Add vertices or Faces

Tags: mesh

how do i fix the gap in my cats nose? there are also holes in the legs that i would like to patch up. :)[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

If you select 2 vertices and press F, a new edge between the vertices is created.
If you right click on it and choose subdivide you can add 1 or more vertices to that edge.
If you select 4 vertices and press F, a face will be created.

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick video demonstrating how you'd go about doing something like this. I hope it helps! If you need more help then feel free to ask

Remember that, if you know that certain parts are going to be animated, then use quads and stay away from triangles. This seems pretty low poly though but quads are always preferred when creating organic things such as this.

[Demonstration](https://youtu.be/CrMY8k1l5dI)